# AngularFire email login issue with newly create Firebase apps

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I realize there's issues between AngularFire and Firebase 3.0 but I could not find a solution to the issue I'm seeing.

Using these versions :

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.7/firebase.js"></script>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.1/angularfire.js"></script>
```

Email / Password authentication agains newly created applications in the new Firebase console do not work.

Legacy apps imported into the new console work using email auth.
Legacy apps in the old console work.
Newly create apps do not.

I've verified the behavior several times.

The console log error is :

Authentication failed: Error: The specified authentication provider is not enabled for this Firebase

I've created a simple pluker here
https://plnkr.co/edit/X025RQmsXfgOFLatp0Ng

based off Jacob Wenger's git repo. https://github.com/jwngr/ng-auth

Comment: You cannot use the Firebase 2.x SDKs on a project that is created in the [new Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/). This has been asked before, so I'll find a duplicate. Note that [AngularFire 2.0 was just released](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire), which works with the latest SDKs.

Comment: I can't get the new version to work with the code I have. I'm getting a.onAuthStateChanged is not a function.  Can anyone point me to a complete working example of Firebase working with angularfire that has authentication?

Comment: A new version of AngularFire was just released (and already updated to 2.0.1). Be sure to check it out and follow along on the issue tracker on Github. This for example sounds like: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/743